# C# update variable in thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am learning threading in C#, and I have a problem :

I have a list of items, and each item refreshes the value of one variable every second, thanks to a `DispatcherTimer`.
Then, I created a thread, with an infinite loop, and send this value.

Maybe the code will be better to understand.

Product :

```
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void notifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private double price;
    public double Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set
        {
            price = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("Price");
        }
    }

    private Timer timer;

    public Product(int time)
    {
        timer = new Timer(time);
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        this.Price = Math.Round(r.NextDouble() * (maxPrice - minPrice) + minPrice, 2);
    }
}
```

Main :

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Thread thread;
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    thread = new Thread(() => createServer(listGroupProduct));
    thread.Start();
}

public static void createServer(ObservableCollection<GroupProducts> list)
{
    string client = "";
    try
    {
        IPAddress ipAdress = IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xx.xx");
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAdress, 1220);

        listener.Start();
        socket = listener.AcceptSocket();

        while (true)
        {
            articlesString = list[0].Price.ToString();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[list.Count * 50];
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(articlesString.ToCharArray());

            socket.Send(bytes);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

My problem is : the value send is always the same, but if I check the value in the main, the value changed...

Have you a solution ?

Comment: Because I have an other program, the client, who need to get the value every second. If you see an other way, I'll be happy to listen to you :)

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but I see no relation between these two source files.

Comment: I don't see where you're using anything from the form in the thread method.  i.e. what is your question?

Comment: Maybe more informations then. the "listGroupProduct" is a list of "Product". My question is : in the list "listGroupProduct", each items has a variable, "Price", and its value change every 5sec. in the form, their value change, and in my thread, not. How can I refresh the list in my thread too ?

Comment: list[0] is always, where is de-queue? Bytes send from "Sender" end and Byte in "Receiving" end are varying?

Comment: No. In listGroupProduct, each item has a "Price" variable. Each second, in the timer's tick, this value change. In my thread, the value doesnt change, whereas in the main, out of my thread, the value changed.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `private double price;` as `private volatile double price;` since it's used by multiple threads.

You might want to read: http://www.andrewdenhertog.com/c/thread-safe-lock-volatile-and-interlock-in-c/

Comment: The problem is the same. The value send never change in my thread, whereas in my list, out of the thread, the value changed...